# How to run multiple pipelines (in parallel) in Zuul?

Tags: gerrit, zuul-ci

I am new to Zuul. I could install Zuul 8.3.1 version as per the instructions mentioned in the Quick Installation: https://zuul-ci.org/docs/zuul/8.3.1/tutorials/quick-start.html

However, when I submit for code review using Gerrit, the zuul check pipeline is triggered. But if I place one more code review of any other repo, it just get queued until the first get completed.

I referred several articles - regarding multiple executors or creating nodepool with more than once instance, but all were in vain.

Can anyone guide me how to proceed further?